Hare Krsna mantra in Brahmanda Puran
Recently, I have come across various blogs which have mentioned that the Hare Krsna mantra is mentioned in the Brahmanda Puran.
The transliteration cited is as follows-
(Brahmanda Purana 6.59)
nama sankirtana deva tarakam brahma drsyatehare krishna hare krishna krishna krishna hare harehare rama hare rama rama rama hare hare
I am not able to find the Brahmanda Puran online from where I can get this exact verse.
It will be really helpful if the link to Brahmanda Puran's this exact verse be provided.
Hari Om Tat Sat.

Must be from an older manuscript of the Purana which is no longer available. Hare Krishna.

ISKCON Organization Claims Hare Krishna Mantra In Brahmanda Puran, But ISKCON Organization Doesnt Mentions In Which Khand Adhyay Sloka
Hare Krishna Mantra Is Originally In Kalisantarana Upanishad Which Mentions Hare Ram First Then Hare Krishn, But ISKCON Organization Changed Hare Krishna First And Then Hare Rama And Pronounciation From Ram To Rama From Krshn To Krishna
Hare Krishna Jai Shree Krishna
Jai Shree Ram
Jai Mata Di Jai Shiv Shankar Har Har Mahadev Om Namah Shivaaya

But isn’t it every Gaudiya Vaishnav Sampradya affiliated institution chant Hare Krsna first? And not just ISKCON?
